# smoothness, differentiability and continuity of a parametric curve

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors

Hi I am reviewing basic vector calculus for geometry and stuck on two very elementary facts.

First,
A parametric curve $r=r(t)$, $a\le t\le b$ is called smooth if

1) $r'(t)$ exists;

2) $r'(t)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$ and

3) $r'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t$ in $(a,b)$.

Here my confusion is, if 1) holds, why do I still need to state 2)? Doesn't the existence of derivative guarantee continuity on the same interval?

Next, I wish to define **smoothness** for a parameterised curves. By definition,
A parameterised smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth (i.e. infinite differentiable) map $\alpha: I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ from an open interval $I=(a,b)$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here, my question is, does infinite differentiability gurantee all derivatives are continuous?

Hope anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $r'(t)$ exists, then certainly $r(t)$ is continuous (as you say, differentiability implies continuity). But condition #1 does not imply condition #2 because condition #2 talks about continuity of $r'(t)$, not continuity of $r(t)$.

Regarding your second question ...

Yes, if a curve is infinitely differentiable, then all of its derivatives exist and are continuous. Specifically, the existence of the $(n+1)$-th derivative implies that the $n$-th derivative is continuous.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Could you also look at my edited question?

Comment: You really ought to ask a new question, but, anyway ... Yes, if a curve is infintitely differentiable, then all of its derivatives exist and are continuous. Specifically, the existence of the $(n+1)$-th derivative implies that the $n$-th derivative is continuous.

Comment: Note that your question states two defintions of "smooth" and they are different. The second one is much stronger than the first.

Comment: what do you mean by two definition of "smooth". Do you mean smoothness of a parametric curve is different from smoothness of a parameterised curve? If yes, why?

Comment: A parametric curve and a parameterized curve are the same thing. Your first definition requires only that the first derivative is continuous; your second definition requires that **all** derivatives are continuous.

Comment: i appreciate for this